# On zoom out, some webfonts resize and some do not

Tags: css, webfonts, zooming

I'm working on a site that uses several webfonts. We zoom out in the browser -- one of the webfonts resizes down proportionally and the other two do not. Any idea why? And is there a way to force the fonts to resize down proportionally?

Answer (score 0):

Try and set your font sizes to "em" instead of "px"

Per [this reference](https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent):

> em is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. An em is
> equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the font-size of the
> document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems are scalable in nature, so
> 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt, etc. Ems are becoming
> increasingly popular in web documents due to scalability and their
> mobile-device-friendly nature.